# Auto starting application on boot

Tags: linux, centos-6

I have two applications that I am having trouble with: memcached and supervisord

At the moment each time i reboot the server i need to remember to run

```
memcached -d -u regularUser
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
supervisorctl start laravel-backup:*
supervisorctl start laravel-restore:*
supervisorctl start laravel-default:*
```

Which is not practical if for what ever reason server ends up reboots in the night.

I have run 'chkconfig memcached on' and 'chkconfig supervisord on'.

The /etc/init.d/memcached look like this (a snipped):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# memcached    Startup script for memcached processes
#
# chkconfig: - 90 10
# description: Memcache provides fast memory based storage.
# processname: memcached

[ -f memcached ] || exit 0

prog="memcached"

start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog "

    memcached -d -u regularUser

    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}
```

/etc/init.d/supervisord look like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord
#
# Supervisor is a client/server system that
# allows its users to monitor and control a
# number of processes on UNIX-like operating
# systems.
#
# chkconfig: - 64 36
# description: Supervisor Server
# processname: supervisord

# Source init functions
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

prog="supervisord"

prefix="/usr/"
exec_prefix="${prefix}"
prog_bin="${exec_prefix}/bin/supervisord"
PIDFILE="/var/run/$prog.pid"

start()
{
       echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
       daemon $prog_bin --pidfile $PIDFILE
       [ -f $PIDFILE ] && success $"$prog startup" || failure $"$prog startup"

supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
supervisorctl start laravel-backup:*
supervisorctl start laravel-restore:*
supervisorctl start laravel-default:*
       echo
}
```

What am I doing wrong; how can my problem be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace hyphen (-) with 2345 in the following lines in both scripts

```
# chkconfig: - 64 36
# chkconfig: - 90 10
```

Comment: So do you mean that they should change `# chkconfig: - 64 36` to `# chkconfig: 2345 64 36`, etc.?  And why?  This is not very clear.